# How to rationalize nth root in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a Sympy function like sympy.simplify.radsimp.radsimp or sympy.simplify.radsimp.rad_rationalize for rationalizing nth root ? It seems those function work with square roots only.

Many thanks.

Comment: As far as I'm aware `sympy` only goes as far as square root rationisation `radsimp` certainly only does square roots. [From the radsimp docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#module-sympy.simplify.radsimp) **Rationalize the denominator by removing square roots.**.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `real_root` is what you are looking for?

```
>>> from sympy import root, real_root
>>> root(-6,3)
(-6)**(1/3)
>>> real_root(_)
-6**(1/3)
```

Comment: Not actually. I'd like to rationalize the denominator in this expression:

expr = 1/root(x,3)

Rationalising denominator with squared root is very simple by using radsimp function but I couldn't find a way to do that with cubed roots.